# Downloading SQL schema for SVN in Eclipse

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse, svn

I develop PHP apps in Eclipse and I'm wondering, is there an easy way of downloading my MySQL schema to a specific folder so that when I commit to SVN it's included?

EDIT:
I'm using phpMyAdmin to export my schema. I'm just wondering if I can automate this step in Eclipse.

Comment: mysqldump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a little script that contains:

```
mysqldump --no-data DBNAME > /path/to/your/file.sql
```

And run it before committing (does svn support client based hooks?)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use PHPMyAdmin to export your schema? Then you can choose a folder that falls in an appropriate place in an Eclipse Workspace. Following this, check-in to SVN is easy.